# Why is my I class unicode showing in italics?

Tags: html

I have this:

```html
<i class=icon-email>&#x1F4E7;</i>
```

This works, but the icon leans forward, like with italics?

Comment: Your post is lacking reproducible steps, which means users visiting your question and trying to help you won't be able to know why you're faceing this issue. Please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: I think the answer below might have solved it. I'll let you know if not though. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<i>` tag used to show content in italics.

Use `<span>` tag instead.

Comment: Thanks. Will that also solve my problem of icons not showing in desktop? This was why I used i class initially instead of just unicode.